# search multiple fields django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to build a search system, and I want to search by multiple fieldsname, state, city, in my django models. I wrote the below code, yet I've been unable to figure out how to go about it. I use Q but it seems not working:

views.py:

```
def data_consulting(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
          form = FilterForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
                conditions = [('toBuy', form.cleaned_data['toBuy']), ('name__contains', form.cleaned_data['searchName']),(('price__gte', form.cleaned_data['searchPriceBegin']), ('price__lte',form.cleaned_data['searchPriceEnd'])),(('calories__gte', form.cleaned_data['searchCalorieBegin']), ('calories__lte', form.cleaned_data['searchCalorieEnd'])), (('date__gte',form.cleaned_data['DateBegin']), ('date__lte', form.cleaned_data['DateEnd']))]
                all_products = Product.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, [Q(condition) for condition in conditions]))
                send = True
                all_products = Product.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, [Q(condition) for condition in conditions]))
           else:
                form = FilterForm()
                all_products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mealManager/data_consulting.html', locals())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a think about what

```
reduce(operator.or_, [Q(condition) for condition in conditions])
```

becomes with e.g. `[('toBuy', 'bread'), ('name__contains', 'bread')]`. It becomes

```
Q(('toBuy', 'bread')) | Q(('name_contains', 'bread'))
```

which is obviously wrong syntax, since `Q` rather [needs kwargs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) than a tuple:

```
Q(toBuy='bread') | Q(name__contains='bread')
```

that's where the `**` operator comes to the rescue. If you get data like this:

```
[{'toBuy': 'bread'}, {'name__contains': 'bread'}]
```

which may be accomplished by simply changing the `conditions` assignment you can then do

```
reduce(operator.or_, [Q(**condition) for condition in conditions])
```

which translates in the particular case to

```
Q(toBuy='bread') | Q(name__contains='bread')
```

which is exactly what we need.

Comment: Thanks for responding, when i replace Q(condition)  by Q(**condition) i got this error:type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple

Comment: You didn't convert your data to `[{'toBuy': 'bread'}, {'name__contains': 'bread'}]` `**` needs a dict to work with, not a tuple.

Comment: @thebjorn you're right. `or` (aka `||`) is the logic operator while `|` is the binary one (required for `Q`). Fixed.